# PowerPoint 2011 crashes when trying to format shape

Tags: macos, ms-office, crash

Whenever I try to format shape (for example edit line) in PowerPoint it crashes leaving me with this error message:

```
Microsoft Error Reporting log version: 2.0

Error Signature:
Exception: EXC_BAD_ACCESS
Date/Time: 2014-02-20 12:15:50 +0000
Application Name: Microsoft PowerPoint
Application Bundle ID: com.microsoft.Powerpoint
Application Signature: PPT3
Application Version: 14.3.9.131030
Crashed Module Name: WLMGraphicsDevice
Crashed Module Version: 14.3.9.131030
Crashed Module Offset: 0x000165cf
Blame Module Name: WLMGraphicsDevice
Blame Module Version: 14.3.9.131030
Blame Module Offset: 0x000165cf
Application LCID: 1045
Extra app info: Reg=en Loc=0x0415
Crashed thread: 0
```

It's worknig on Mavericks on Polish version

**EDIT**
If it's any help that what I found in system log;

```
Feb 20 14:05:01 MBPTest.local com.apple.IconServicesAgent[316]: main Failed to composit image for binding VariantBinding [0x25d] flags: 0x8 binding: FileInfoBinding [0x353] - extension: ppt, UTI: com.microsoft.powerpoint.ppt, fileType: ????.
Feb 20 14:05:01 MBPTest.local quicklookd[3607]: Warning: Cache image returned by the server has size range covering all valid image sizes. Binding: VariantBinding [0x803] flags: 0x8 binding: FileInfoBinding [0x703] - extension: ppt, UTI: com.microsoft.powerpoint.ppt, fileType: ???? request size:64 scale: 1
```

Comment: It is a known problem already, without solution, other than try reinstalling ms office bundle.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I presume that by "trying to reinstall" you mean that it's not 100% sure that the problem won't occur again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is to completely uninstall MS Office in your local language (Google how to, it's a long and painful process). Then clean install MS Office IN ENGLISH. It worked for me anyway - I've encountered the same weird behaviour on 2 machines with Russian MS Office, while the 3rd (with English one) was running fine. Guess this is just Microsoft's way of saying "learn friggin English, dudes!" :)